# Cannot display letters with accents after upgrade to ubuntu 11.10

Tags: keyboard, input-language

after updating to Ubuntu 11.10, my system doesn´t accept letters with accents- For example if i want to wrote "á" it ends like "´a".
But if i logon with guest account this problem doesn´t exist.
Is it possible to copy any configuration file from guest account to my account?
Any other idea?
Thanks

Comment: have you check your keyboard language?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have selected the wrong keyboard layout on your user account. To change this go to **System Settings** and select the **Keyboard** option.

Here select **Layout Settings** In this window click the + button in the bottom left to add a new keyboard layout

[image]

Select the language that relates to your keyboard (if you can preview the keyboard layout by clicking the **Preview** button to make sure it is the correct layout).

[image]

After you have selected the correct keyboard delete the incorrect keyboard from the list by highlighting it and clicking the **-** button.